# Divs loading side by side in Internet Explorer - Should be top/bottom

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm designing my own portfolio site and only have some basic knowledge about wordpress, html, and CSS. On my individual portfolio pages there is text and a graphic, and the text is supposed to sit higher on the page than the graphic, which will sit below. This works just fine in Firefox, Safari, and Chrome, but it's giving me issues in Internet Explorer, and is creating an issue where the text is sitting to the left of the image, shrinking and smushing the image into a smaller, condensed space.

http://mikeklok.com/portfolio/myt-product-creation-2/

Any way to solve this with CSS? Im not advanced enough to understand how to find and edit the html, as it's not made as easily available as the CSS.

Thanks,

Comment: StackOverflow is not a debugging service! If you have any specific questions, post your [relevant code](http://sscce.org/) here, and we'll try to help you.

Comment: CSS won't do you any good if you don't know how to at least find the html.  You have to know what tags to target with your CSS code.  Being able to edit the HTML is even better.

Answer (score 2):

Your containing div is divided into two separate divs with classes "first column" and "last column" respectively, each specified with the styles `width: 50%; float: left;`. I really wonder why Chrome, FF and Safari make such a mess of it.

Remove those styles, or add `break: both;` to the second one.